# embed wordpress or other php application to a django/python site?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, django

Is that possible to  embed wordpress or other php application to a django/python site ? I am running apache web server on linux...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out myself.

Just redirect the subdomain of using php application to a different location at apache configure

if you like blog.yourdomain.com be a php applicaiton just at a subdomain

at apache configure

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName   blog.yourdomain.com
        UseCanonicalName Off
        ServerAdmin  "contact@yourdomain.com"
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/yourdomain.com/blogapplicaiton
</VirtualHost>
```

and put your php code in /var/www/vhosts/yourdomain.com/blogapplicaiton

you get all other web application through django but blog.yourdomain.com using php applicaiton.